# How to select only a subset of dataframe columns in julia

Tags: julia

I have a Dataframe of several columns say column1, column2...column100. How do I select only a subset of the columns eg (not column1) should return all columns column2...column100.

```
data[[colnames(data) .!= "column1"]])
```

doesn't seem to work.

I don't want to mutate the dataframe. I just want to select all the columns that don't have a particular column name like in my example

Answer (score 19, accepted):

EDIT 2/7/2021: as people seem to still find this on Google, I'll edit this to say right at the top that current DataFrames (1.0+) allows both `Not()` selection supported by [`InvertedIndices.jl`](https://github.com/mbauman/InvertedIndices.jl) and also string types as column names, including regex selection with the `r""` string macro. Examples:

```
julia> df = DataFrame(a1 = rand(2), a2 = rand(2), x1 = rand(2), x2 = rand(2), y = rand(["a", "b"], 2))
2×5 DataFrame
 Row │ a1        a2        x1        x2        y      
     │ Float64   Float64   Float64   Float64   String 
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.784704  0.963761  0.124937  0.37532   a
   2 │ 0.814647  0.986194  0.236149  0.468216  a

julia> df[!, r"2"]
2×2 DataFrame
 Row │ a2        x2       
     │ Float64   Float64  
─────┼────────────────────
   1 │ 0.963761  0.37532
   2 │ 0.986194  0.468216

julia> df[!, Not(r"2")]
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ a1        x1        y      
     │ Float64   Float64   String 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.784704  0.124937  a
   2 │ 0.814647  0.236149  a
```

Finally, the `names` function has a method which takes a type as its second argument, which is handy for subsetting DataFrames by the element type of each column:

```
julia> df[!, names(df, String)]
2×1 DataFrame
 Row │ y      
     │ String 
─────┼────────
   1 │ a
   2 │ a
```

In addition to indexing with square brackets, there's also the `select` function (and its mutating equivalent `select!`), which basically takes the same input as the column index in `[]`-indexing as its second argument:

```
julia> select(df, Not(r"a"))
2×3 DataFrame
 Row │ x1        x2        y      
     │ Float64   Float64   String 
─────┼────────────────────────────
   1 │ 0.124937  0.37532   a
   2 │ 0.236149  0.468216  a
```

Original answer below

---

As @Reza Afzalan said, what you're trying to do returns an array of strings, while column names in DataFrames are symbols.

Given that Julia doesn't have conditional list comprehension, the nicest thing you could do I guess would be

```
data[:, filter(x -> x != :column1, names(df))]
```

This will give you the data set with column 1 removed (without mutating it). You could extend this to checking against lists of names as well:

```
data[:, filter(x -> !(x in [:column1,:column2]), names(df))]
```

UPDATE: As Ian says below, for this use case the `Not` syntax is now the best way to go.

More generally, conditional list comprehensions are also available by now, so you could do:

```
data[:, [x for x in names(data) if x != :column1]]
```

Comment: The [docs](http://juliastats.github.io/DataFrames.jl/subsets/) mention using a set of names as selection, although do not go very deep on ways you can define such a set

Comment: Anything wrong with ``data[!, 2:ncol(df)]`` to select all except the first column? Thanks.

Comment: Nothing wrong with that, although if you go that way I would probably write it as `data[!, 2:end]`

Answer (score 17):

As of DataFrames 0.19, seems that you can now do

```
select(data, Not(:column1))
```

to select all but the column `column1`.  To select all except for multiple columns, use an array in the inverted index:

```
select(data, Not([:column1, :column2]))
```

Comment: just make sure all columns being dropped exist in data, else raises `ArgumentError: column  not found in the data frame`

Answer (score 4):

To select several columns by name:

```
 df[[:col1, :col2]
```

or, for other versions of the DataFrames library, I use:

```
select(df, [:col1, :col2])
```

Comment: This works great. In this case it returns a copy of the dataframe columns. I think equivalent is `df[:, [:col1, :col2]]`.  To get a reference to the same dataframes columns (dont make a copy), use `df[!, [:col1, :col2]]`

Answer (score 3):

`colnames(data) .!= "column1"` # => returns an array of bool

I think the right way is to use a **filter function** that returns desired column names

`filter(x->x != "column1", colnames(data))` # => returns an array of string

DataFrame column names are of Symbol datatype

`map(symbol ,str_array_of_filterd_column_names)` # => returns array of identical symbols

Answer (score 2):

One way is selecting a range of columns using the index

`idx = length(data)
data[2:idx]`

Other ways to do conditional selection are in the [DataFrames docs](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Introducing_Julia/DataFrames#Selecting_rows_with_conditions)